# How do I plug custom partition logic in WriteKafkaP?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I'm using the `WriteKafaP` vertex in a Jet job. Is there a way to plug in custom partition logic when publishing to the Kafka topic?

Comment: You mean you want to determine the partition, to which the event will be published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.4, you can use a [custom Kafka partitioner configuration](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/06/04/write-apache-kafka-custom-partitioner/). In 0.5, we added the ability to map the item to a `ProducerRecord` directly.

For example:

`Vertex v = new Vertex("kafkaSink", KafkaProcessors.writeKafkaP(properties, o -> new ProducerRecord(topic, partition, key, value));`